# using document.getElementsByTagName doesn't find elements added dynamically (IE6)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6

I am trying to write a method that grabs all the elements of a certain classname for browsers that don't have the 'getElementsByClassName' method. This works perfectly for elements that are generated server-side, however the page has the ability to add elements dynamically for some reason 'window.document.all' does not get these dynamic elements. Any ideas? Method below.

```
function getClassName(class) {
        var i, neededStuff = [], elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

        for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            if (elements[i].className == class) {
                neededStuff[neededStuff.length] = elements[i];
            }
        }
        return neededStuff;
    }
```

Comment: what does it have to do with `getElementsByTagName`?

Comment: oops, i was using getElementsByTagName, but then switched it to 'window.document.all' to test something before i posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`class` is a reserved keyword in IE. Don't use it literally. Change `class` to something like `theClass`.

Also, try `document.getElementsByTagName('*')` instead of `document.all` if changing `class` doesn't do it.

**EDIT:**

http://work.arounds.org/sandbox/72

Works perfectly for me in IE6 ^

Let me try dynamically adding...

**EDIT #2:** works fine..

http://work.arounds.org/sandbox/72

Comment: +1 Should probably use `getElementsByTagName` either way since `document.all` [is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document).

Comment: @invaderkay - your getClassName is too simple. Why not use a more complex version? You are doing `className ==`. Class can contain multiple values.

Comment: so, i'm an idiot. this was working the entire time, however i was setting the dynamic elements class with 'setAttribute('class', 'name') instead of 'element.className ='. Thanks for the example.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery :)

http://jquery.com/

```
$('.ClassName')
```

will return your elements :)

then you can change it's value, add classes very easily!

Some great tutorials here

http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials

Comment: This should be a comment since it does nothing to address the issue in the code presented.

Comment: @patrick True... It was basically a "stop what you are doing and use jQuery" type of answer :) And jQuery is IE6 compatible.

Comment: jQuery is not always the most appropriate solution.